How can I run NET USE if the password starts with a slash?
I'm trying to run the Windows net.exe program to connect to a computer (escaping double quotes on the passwords):
NET USE \\computer /USER:domain\user "%password:"=""%"

But I notice this isn't working for a password starting with a slash ("/"), as it's taken as a keyword:
C:\> NET USE \\computer /USER:domain\user "/password"
The option /PASSWORD is unknown

The syntax of this command is:
...

Some sites suggest using redirection
echo asdf|net use \\comp /user:dom\user *

net use \\comp /user:dom\user *<password.txt

But these ways aren't working (anymore?), at least on my Windows 10 (version 10.0.19045.4529) machine, with NET nor RUNAS, not even using asdf as password.
So, is there any way I can run NET USE if the password starts with a slash?

I wonder what happens if you replace /PASSWORD with //PASSWORD, to see if it escapes it

Same error, nothing changes at all: The option //PASSWORD is unknown. [...]

There's no way to workaround these cases.
I ended up putting in a validation to notify the user that a password starting with "/" are not supported, so they have to modify it to make it work.
